# Meaning of "It is easy to locate an object on flat surface with reference to other object."

Tags: american-english, british-english

It is easy to locate an object on flat surface with reference to other object.

I understood the meaning of "with reference to" is in relation to from google

Can you explain it in simple speech?

**Source**

[image]

Comment: Your question is confused.  The source text has "with reference to".  But your question has "with respect to".  You say that you understand "with reference to" (from google).  Why are you asking about "with respect to"?  That doesn't appear in the source.  It would mean the same as "with reference to" and the same as "in relation to".

Comment: Sorry James, that was typo. Please disregard "with respect to", It is with reference to.

Comment: Town B is thirty miles due east of Town A. This tells us B's location _with reference to_ A (using A as our _point of reference_).

Comment: It's a poor text: the problem is exactly the same with flat surfaces and curved ones, but in two dimensions or three. Both need a reference point *and* orientation. Perhaps the author was thinking of a page of a book, which has a defined corner and orientation.